# How to get average of time(7) field in sql Server query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to get average of a time field in sql server but this time(7) field actually is sort of a timespan for my project, let say I have 2 record of active time of for each of my hives and I want to group it by hive number and have average of those 2 record

active time is between `00:00:00` and `24:00:00`

my table is

```
   int          time(7)
HiveNumber    ActiveTime
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
   1           14:12:12
   1           10:10:00
   2           13:15:55
   2           12:55:55
```

and I want a Select Command Like this

```
Select HiveNumber,
       Avg(ActiveTime)
       from tHivesGenetic 

Group by HiveNumber
```

but `Operand data type datetime is invalid for avg operator`

Comment: What do you mean by average of time? For example between 14:12:12 and 10:10:00?

Comment: Hint: `SELECT DATEDIFF_BIG(NANOSECOND, 0, CONVERT(TIME(7), '23:59:59'))`. If you don't need it to nanosecond precision, definitely go lower -- `AVG` just does `SUM / COUNT` under water, so it can overflow, given enough rows.

Comment: @EdwardN l mean I have 2 record of active time I want sum of 2 record and divide it by 2 to get average of colony active time i

Comment: As commented on the other question, average doesn't make sense here since `time` represents a *time of day*, not a *time span*. In any decent type system, those should be represented by two separate (but related) data types. This is also why `time` doesn't support negative values nor values greater than 24 hours which are both also useful concepts for time *spans*.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Hi, tanks I can do that to get second of 1 record, but can you give me a hint to how do that for multiple record? for example how to get total second for 2 record of one hive?